# Reverse for 'submit_review' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['submit_review/(?P<game_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, review

l got an error when trying to create the form for Star Ratings, to me l have failed to get the mistake for the erroor  it returns. so, am requesting
anyone who knows, to help me and solve that error, thanks I'm Samuel

**Below is the browser error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /action/3444/

Reverse for 'submit_review' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['submit_review/(?P<game_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/action/3444/

Django Version: 4.1.6

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'submit_review' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['submit_review/(?P<game_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Exception Location: C:\N2G-PROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix

Raised during:  Action.views.action_description

Python Executable:  C:\N2G-PROJECT\venv\Scripts\python.exe

Python Version: 3.10.0

Python Path:    

['C:\\n2g-project\\my_site',

 'C:\\Users\\AdminSb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',

 'C:\\Users\\AdminSb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',

 'C:\\Users\\AdminSb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',

 'C:\\Users\\AdminSb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',

 'C:\\N2G-PROJECT\\venv',

 'C:\\N2G-PROJECT\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 28 Mar 2023 22:52:52 +0000
```

**Below are my Code editor codes (Vs code)**

```
**#Action/urls.py**

urlpatterns = [

    path('action', views.action , name='action'),

    path('action/<slug:description>/', views.action_description, name='action_description'),

    path('submit_review/<int:game_id>/', views.submit_review, name='submit_review')

]
```

```
**#Action/forms.py**

class Game_ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': "write Review"}))

    class Meta:

        model= ActionReview

        fields=['subject','content','stars']
```

```
**#Action/views.py**

def submit_review(request,game_id):

    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:

            reviews = ActionReview.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id, game_name__id=game_id)

            form = Game_ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)

            form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Thank you! , Your review has been Updated Successfully.')

            return redirect(url)

        except ActionReview.DoesNotExist:

            form =Game_ReviewForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                data=ActionReview()

                data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']

                data.stars = form.cleaned_data['stars']

                data.content = form.cleaned_data['content']

                data.game_id=game_id

                data.user__id=request.user.id

                data.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! , Your review has been Added Successfully.')

                return redirect(url)
```

```
**#action-description.html**

......

    <hr>

    <form action="{% url 'submit_review' description.id %}" method="POST">

      {% csrf_token %}

      <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

     

      <h2 class="h5">Please how do you feel with this Game?</h2>.........
```

**Anyone to solve me, l will be glad and I would like to know the route of the error**

I expected a working form but I got lost where l did the mistake

Comment: Try using keyword arguments in the URL tag, like: `{% url 'submit_review' game_id=description.id %}` ..these template error are so hard to narrow down, the traces SUCK! :(

Comment: Where do you try to reverse `submit_review` without an argument? Because clearly not in that template. Also the error message mentioned `Action.views.action_description` but you included a different view function.